# React native Loading indicators in axios interceptor not getting diplayed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, axios

I am new to react and react-native. I am trying to display a global Loading indicator for HTTP requests using the Axios interceptor. I am using redux in my app. But the problem is whenever I make HTTP calls in my app (in other components like App component) loading indicator is not getting displayed.

What I am doing wrong? Here is the flow

1. Importing Axios file in the main App component.
2. Setup action and reducer for showing and hiding loader.
3. Using a separate component called `HttpLoading` component for showing loader. This component gets state from redux using mapStatetoProps
4. Finally importing `HttpLoader` component in the main App component

But still, the loader is not getting displayed if I make an HTTP request in the App component or any other component. My goal is to show a global loader for all HTTP requests.

Thank you in advance.

axios.ts

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '../redux/store';
import { START_LOADING, FINISH_LOADING } from '../redux/types/loadingTypes'

axios.interceptors.request.use(async function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    console.log("show loading")

    store.dispatch({type : START_LOADING, payload : true})
    
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
      console.log(error)
      store.dispatch({type : FINISH_LOADING, payload : false})
      console.log("finish loading")

      // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response data
    store.dispatch({type : FINISH_LOADING, payload : false})
    console.log("finish loading")

    return response;
  }, function (error) {

    store.dispatch({type : FINISH_LOADING, payload : false})
    console.log("finish loading")
    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

loadingType.ts

```
export const START_LOADING = 'START_LOADING'
export const FINISH_LOADING = 'FINISH_LOADING'
```

loadingAction.ts

```
import { START_LOADING , FINISH_LOADING } from '../types/loadingTypes'

    export const Loading_action = (bool : boolean)=>{
        return bool ? {
          type: START_LOADING ,
          data:bool
        }: {
          type: FINISH_LOADING ,
          data: bool
        }
      }
```

loadingReducer.ts

```
import { START_LOADING, FINISH_LOADING, Loading , LoadingActions } from '../types/loadingTypes'

    const initialState : Loading = {
        active_loading : 0,
    }
    
    const loadinReducer = (state = initialState, action : LoadingActions) => {
    
            switch(action.type) {
                case START_LOADING : {
                    state.active_loading++;
                    return action.payload
                }
        
                case FINISH_LOADING : {
                    state.active_loading--;
                    return action.payload
                }
        
                default : return state
            }
        }
        
        export default loadinReducer
```

App.tsx

```
import './shared/axiosInterceptor'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './redux/store'
// other imports     
  return (
    <>

      <Provider store={store}>
        <AuthLoading />
        <HttpLoading />
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
};


export default App
```

httpLoading.tsx // HTTP loading component

```
import { Loading_action } from '../redux/actions/loadingActions'
// other imports 
  const HttpLoading: React.FC<props> = ({ loading }) => { 
        return (
            loading.active_loading > 0 ? 
                <View style={styles.horizontal}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#00ff00" />
                </View> : null
        )
    
    }
    
    const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
        loading: state.loading,
    });
    
    export default connect
        (mapStateToProps, { Loading_action })
        (HttpLoading)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? does finish loading and start loading being displayed on console.log?

Comment: Yes. Console.logs get displayed for every Http request

Comment: Try doing some console.log inside HttpLoading to see what value does loading have.
Because it's an object - I recommend doing console.log(JSON.stringify(loading)) to see the exact state at the time of printing.

Comment: Okay. Let me check